# Connecting to MySQL from Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

The MySQL database is located on my local computer and I can't figure out how to connect to it. I dropped an SQLDataSource object onto my page and I'm trying to create a new connection but can't figure out how to do it. Help please!

I've already downloaded the connectors for .NET but have no idea what to do with them =S

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered before: [ASP .NET - Configure SQLDataSource to use MySQL .NET Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065615/asp-net-configure-sqldatasource-to-use-mysql-net-connector)

Don't forget to add

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

to your class.