# ASP.NET I can't get my datasource/gridview to function since switching from SQL to Access DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ms-access, gridview

I have a school project due soon, it is a web app in ASP.NET and I thought I had finished and had it working as intended using a local MySQL database. My professor has recently instructed us to change our database to MS Access and I have successfully made the switch all bar one of my classes. The class in question takes the people registered from my DB table, and lists it in a gridview, with a filter and converting the DOB into age. I will include my code along with a screenshot of the error. From looking around I found that you can configure a SqlDataSource to work with an access DB so I followed the steps and this is the error I am now getting; 'The connection name 'newregDBConnectionString.System.Data.OleDb' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.'

Can anyone help me to see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

My Web.config;

```
<add name="newregDBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
 Data Source=C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Database1.accdb"
 providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

The steps I followed to configure SqlDataSource with an access DB;

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
ID="source"
runat ="server" 
ConnectionString ="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString %>"
ProviderName ="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString.System.Data.OleDb %>"
SelectCommand= "SELECT firstname, childID, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children ORDER BY age"   />
```

My C# code where I'm trying to display the gridview;

```
namespace Coursework
{
public partial class Testy1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //create a datasource
    SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource();     

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //always set some defaults for the datasource
        source.ID = "source1";
        source.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionStr‌ing;
        source.SelectCommand = "SELECT firstname, childID, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children ORDER BY age";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //bind the grid
            GridView1.DataSource = source;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }       
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the new database query, now with where clause
        source.SelectCommand = "SELECT firstname, childID, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children WHERE (DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 BETWEEN @start AND @end) ORDER BY age";

        //get the end age from the dropdown and cast as int
        int end = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

        //get the start int for the filter
        int start = end - 2;

        //if the filter is resetted, make sure the query returns all ages
        if (end == 5)
        {
            start = 5;
            end = 99;
        }

        //replace the parameters in the query
        source.SelectParameters.Add("start", start.ToString());
        source.SelectParameters.Add("end", end.ToString());

        //rebind the grid
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string childID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string deleteSql = "DELETE FROM Children WHERE childID = @childID; ";
        using (var con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionStr‌​ing))
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(deleteSql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@childID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = childID;
            con.Open();
            int deleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void backBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `<asp:AccessDataSource ID="source" runat="server" DataFile="[Access DB file path]" ... />`? `SqlDataSource` used for SQL Server, where Access DB should use `AccessDataSource`.

Comment: Hi @TetsuyaYamamoto, I tried what you suggested but now I get an error; 'Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The AccessDataSource ConnectionString property cannot be set, it is automatically generated.' 

I was following this guide "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c(v=vs.85).aspx" that showed me how I can use an SqlDataSource with an access DB. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I forgot to tell that you cannot use `ConnectionString` attribute in `AccessDataSource`, it should use `DataFile` with DB file path. Also check this for usage of `SqlDataSource` with Access DB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Ah thank you! But that article is the same as the one I linked above that I have been using already :). The bottom box in the article which shows the following as an example; <asp:SqlDataSource 
   ID="SqlDataSource1"
   runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CustomerDataConnectionString %>"
   ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CustomerDataConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Customers"   />

That is the same example I followed initially, which you can see in the second snippet of code I linked above.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto and neither your way (changing to accessdatasource, nor the articles way works). When I change it to accessdatasource, remove the connection string and add the DataFile=DBfilepath I then get this error; 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The connection name 'newregDBConnectionString.System.Data.OleDb' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty..

Comment: I see that `ProviderName` property usage is wrong there, it should use either `ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString.providerName` or `System.Data.OleDb` as its value (will explain at answer in minutes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137043/discussion-between-acostea-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).

Answer (score 0):

The `ProviderName` attribute value in `SqlDataSource` is used in wrong format:

```
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString.System.Data.OleDb %>"
```

From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c(v=vs.85).aspx), `providerName` property in `ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString.providerName` data source binding refers to `providerName` attribute value in web.config connection string element. Hence, you should leave `providerName` property as is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="source" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString %>"
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newregDBConnectionString.providerName %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT firstname, childID, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children ORDER BY age" />
```

or use provider name directly:

```
ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb"
```

Related issue (see how `providerName` property being used in similar way):

[ASP .NET - Configure SQLDataSource to use MySQL .NET Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065615/asp-net-configure-sqldatasource-to-use-mysql-net-connector)

Comment: thank you for all of your help so far. I used the snippet of code for the datasource that you provided and I now get an error; An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'provider'. 

This error is pointing at the; "GridView1.DataBind();" code